# Caddyfile with multiple Single Page Applications

Tags: single-page-application, caddy, caddyfile

Let's say I have following file structure:

```
- Caddyfile
- files
  - app1
    - index.html
  - app2
    - index.html
  - app3
    - index.html
```

Where `app1`, `app2` and `app3` are Single Page Applications with clientside routing. I am using Caddy v2. I want to route `/app1/*` to `app1` directory and likewise other two, falling back to respective `index.html` in case searched for file doesn't exist.

I think that for one app correct configuration is:

```
handle /app1/* {
  file_server {
    root ./files/app1
    try_files {path} /index.html 
  }
}
```

And that I can just repeat this once for each app. I want to know if it is possible to define this more succintly, since our company currently has 20-30 SPAs, for example with something like:

```
file_server {
    root ./files
    try_files {path} {Maybe something here?}/index.html 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
@spa path_regexp spa ^(.*[\\\/])

handle @spa {
    root * ./files
    try_files {path} {path}.html {path}/ {path}/index.html {re.spa.1}/index.html    
    file_server
}
```

Regex matches everything before last slash, so for example in `/files/app1/clientroute` matched is `/files/app1/`. Then we use this match in `{re.spa.1}/index.html` and so reroute to `/files/app1/index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
  root ./files
  try_files {path} {path}/index.html
  file_server
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer when I get time to try it.

Comment: This doesn't really work - it works for a single SPA, not multiple SPA-s in subdirectories. See my own self-answer for approach with multiple spas.